# ZFS on ramdrive optimal settings

Tags: debian, zfs, proxmox, ramdisk

After failing to configure ZFS for file creation and deletion without subsequent disk IO ([Ramdisk like ZFS behavior](https://serverfault.com/questions/883393/ramdisk-like-zfs-behavior)), I'm creating ZFS over ramdrive.

What to do with compression (but that part I could test by myself if nobody tested it before):

- ZFS no compression + ZRAM
- ZFS with compression + BRD
- ZFS no compression + BRD

How better to configure ZFS? Disable/minimize ARC & ZIL? Something else?
I have another pool on HDD, so better to use pool settings and not system ones.

I have an option to use LVM thin on top of ramdrive instead of ZFS (both proxmox and docker directly support LVM thin pool as storage) and I guess it will be more efficient to use it instead of ZFS, but it is easier to manage ZFS and to use zfs send/receive for saving/restoring ramdrive to HDD.

So if ZFS could be configured for ramdrive, I would prefer that option.

Comment: I'm sorry... it seems like you have a solution that you want to use (ZFS), but are trying to find ways to justify it... ZFS is not a great option for what you're doing.

Comment: @ewwhite, what solution do you propose? I don't want to use ZFS at any cost, I'm trying to minimize my efforts for supporting next use case: creating and deleting proxmox vms, proxmox containers and docker containers which have a lot of IO, without using slow disks and I have a lot of memory which I can use instead of disks. I've tried lvm first and it works, but for me it is harder to maintain, zfs require less efforts, but I assume it will be less efficient without tuning, tmpfs would not work in that scenario.